# What are the advantages of checking for objects with Objects.nonNull()?

Tags: java, null

Our project [changed](https://github.com/kitodo/kitodo-production/commit/3f8fa8e452805a6d235b2dba82236b541f80874f#diff-3671c30e69a2e85e36b2fa88ddc2bf54753c017ae8c0190466a5d52e79b2fb30) the object existence checks from `foo == null` or `foo != null` to `Objects.isNull(foo)` or `Objects.nonNull(foo)`. I never got an explanation why that should be better, that's why I ask.

I’ve been programming in Pascal, C, Perl, Java for a long time and have always checked for inequality with `!=`. This systax is pretty common and any programmer who sees it knows what it does right away. Now we have a function where at least when you see it for the first time you have to check what it is actually doing (similar to C++, but I see that as a deterioration). I’ll admit, I still think that calling a function is an extra jump in the program, there has to be an extra element on the stack, I know compilers can inline that these days, but it still seems strange to me for a basic function to call a one-line function that only encapsulates this function. That change was a year and a half ago and I still stumble over it. [The Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull-java.lang.Object-) comments on the function: “This method exists to be used as a Predicate” but it leaves me alone, which is the advantage of using this function *everywhere*.

So I would like to ask **what are the advantages of this approach?** Is it a better object-oriented style? Does it have any benefit in debugging, unit testing, static code analysis, or does it matter in another context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ask the people who made the change in your project.

I'm with you, there is no advantage to doing this everywhere, and the Javadoc pretty much implies it as well - the methods were *created* to be used via method references.